# Whose spell list(s) is Greater Status on?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, domains

The spell [Status, Greater](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/status) does not appear on any spell list. Its lesser version appears on the cleric and witch spell lists. Its suppose to appear in the [community](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/community-domain) domain but when you visit it you see imbue with spell ability.

So who can cast the spell or how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was intrigued by this question, so while I didn't have any knowledge myself I was able to find an interesting [source](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rn6z?Greater-Status-spell#2) on the Paizo forums addressing this issue:

> Pathfinder Chronicles - Campaign Setting is, technically speaking, not a "Pathfinder RPG" book. It is an OGL DND 3.5 book that that came out in 2008 and pre-dates the stand-alone game known as "Pathfinder RPG" which was launched in 2009. It's a 3rd party add-on to Wizard of the Coast's DND 3.5.
>
> These OGL 3.5 books are often allowed by Pathfinder RPG GMs, but you need to take them with a grain of salt as the rules and mechanics in these OGL 3.5 books don't always match up with the "Pathfinder RPG" rules and mechanics.
>
> The Community Domain in this pre-Pathfinder RPG book is as follows:
>
> Granted Power: Cast Calm Emotions 1/d as a spell-like ability. +2 competence bonus on Diplomacy checks.
> Domain Spells: 1-Bless, 2-Status, 3-Prayer, 4-Greater Status, 5-Telepathic Bond, 6-Heroes' Feast, 7-Refuge, 8-Sympathy, 9-Mass Heal

Essentially this means that, according to *Pathfinder RPG* rules as written, no one can cast the spell Greater Status. According to the *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* rules (and by extension, the third-party *Pathfinder* supplements for *D&D 3.5*), clerics of the Community domain can prepare and cast this spell as a domain spell.

Of course, most 3.5 versions of the *Pathfinder* material were ported over when *Pathfinder RPG* was created, so it's a bit surprising that a spell as innocuous as this was not. It's entirely possible that the spell was overlooked during the transition, and I see nothing that a GM should worry about balance-wise in allowing Community domain clerics to cast the spell instead of their existing 4th level domain spell, [Imbue with Spell Ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/imbue-with-spell-ability).

Comment: I did not know any of that, thanks for the history

Comment: For reference, the spell [*greater status*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/spells/statusGreater.htm) is part of the *D&D 3.5* SRD, too, as the 4th-level [Community domain](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/domains.htm) spell. No need for 3rd-party in that game.

Comment: Additionally, in 3.5, it can be found in _Book of Exalted Deeds_ as a 4th-level spell for both cleric and apostle of peace, and another version of the spell, with different statistics and abilities, can be found in _Heroes of Battle_ as a 5th-level cleric/6th-level healer spell.